# Optimize field of vision algorithm in a grid tiled map

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tilemap, grid

I am trying to implement Field of View algorithm in my game and I followed the great tutorial here : [sight-and-light](http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/) and here is what I got so far :

[image]

As you can see it works fine for me :)

And then I try to use this algorithm in a tiled map. It also works fine but just a little bit slow so I am now trying to find a way to optimize the algorithm.

Some information might help to optimize :

- The tiled map is Orthogonal
- All the tiles have the same size 32 * 32 and are square
- Tiles marked 0 means empty marked as 1 means a obstacle
- I have used Connected Component Labelling algorithm for a preprocess :

  - All the obstacles have been merged into several regions
  - I know all the vertices position in each regions

Something like this :

[image]

Say I have 9 connected regions ( 9 polygons ) and 40 vertices in total.

Based on the algorithm in the above link, there will be :

- ray-cast : 40 * 3   ( 3 ray-cast per vertices in angle +- 0.00001)
- edges : 40
- edge * ray-cast intersection test : 40 * 40 * 3 == 4800

I think there should be a way to reduce the ray cast count and the edges count that I need to do the intersection calculation in a above situation but just could not figure out a good solution.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [roguelike community's collection](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Field_of_Vision), especially the [comparative study](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Comparative_study_of_field_of_view_algorithms_for_2D_grid_based_worlds). They have studied the field of vision problem for grids.

Comment: Check the answer to a similar problem here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/138004/98316